# error TS2552: Cannot find name 'Windows' for @types/winrt-uwp

Tags: angular, typescript, uwp, windows-runtime, angular6

In  an angular 6  project hosted in windows 10 os,

I launch command:

```
npm install --save @types/winrt-uwp
```

It should allow me to use winRT capabalities and write code:

```
  public showToast(message, iconUrl) {
    if (
      typeof Windows !== "undefined" &&
      typeof Windows.UI !== "undefined" &&
      typeof Windows.UI.Notifications !== "undefined"
    ) {
      var notifications = Windows.UI.Notifications;
      var template = notifications.ToastTemplateType.toastImageAndText01;
      var toastXml = notifications.ToastNotificationManager.getTemplateContent(
        template
      );
      var toastTextElements = toastXml.getElementsByTagName("text");
      toastTextElements[0].appendChild(toastXml.createTextNode(message));
      var toastImageElements = toastXml.getElementsByTagName("image");
      var newAttr = toastXml.createAttribute("src");
      newAttr.value = iconUrl;
      var altAttr = toastXml.createAttribute("alt");
      altAttr.value = "toast graphic";
      var attribs = toastImageElements[0].attributes;
      attribs.setNamedItem(newAttr);
      attribs.setNamedItem(altAttr);
      var toast = new notifications.ToastNotification(toastXml);
      var toastNotifier = notifications.ToastNotificationManager.createToastNotifier();
      toastNotifier.show(toast);
    }
  }
```

But when I want to start the project I have the error message:

> error TS2552: Cannot find name 'Windows'. Did you mean 'Window'?

However I can a file `node_modules/@types/winrt-uwp/index.d.ts` which contains

```
 ...
declare namespace Windows {
...
}
..
```

Do you have an idea about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to be able to use the winRT features you must add this code at top of file the maint.ts

```
/// <reference types="@types/winrt-uwp" />
```

And configure angular.json in that way

```
    "options": {
             ...
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
             ...
          },
```